# Automating sandbox post-refresh steps

Tags: sandbox, automation, sandbox-refresh

We are doing monthly refreshes on sandboxes which is causing us to manually do certain things.

1. Deactivate some users and add developer user for testing in sandbox.
2. Change webservice connection details to point to dev environments.

How can we automate these tasks of creating users after refresh for developers in sandbox only and change connection strings on webservices?
Do you guys have any apex class which does this now?

Comment: How do you have your connection details stored?

Comment: In custom settings

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19117/execute-an-apex-class-using-ant-build-script) which has a discussion about running an apex class from ANT. Simply write your apex class to set the custom setting values and create the users then run the ANT command as needed.

You could also use selenium [as discussed here](http://blog.force365.com/2013/01/15/salesforce-ant-and-selenium/) that could automate any standard UI button pressing.

Answer (score 0):

force.com CLI could be used to script these kind of things. It's possible to both update data and run annonymous APEX.