# Is there a way to schedule a schedulable class during deployment using Migration Tool?

Tags: scheduled-apex, migration-tool

I would like to add a schedule to my `Schedulable` class during the deployment of my code via Salesforce Migration Tool.

For example, one might schedule a class as per this example:

```
scheduledMerge m = new scheduledMerge();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Merge Job', sch, m);
```

Is there a way to script the schedule creation during deployment with the Salesforce Migration Tool? If not with the Migration Tool itself, is there any other way of automating this?

Comment: please see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19117/execute-an-apex-class-using-ant-build-script/19120#19120

Answer (score 0):

You could have another job on a schedule whose job it is to schedule this job in question if it isn't already scheduled. I can't think of another way since you can't exercise apex on a deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use the [Force.com CLI](https://force-cli.heroku.com) and ANT execute to run the APEX code to schedule the class.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to of automating the deployement is right now is CI, you go ["Continuous Integration How-To"](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Continuous_Integration_How-To)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks for editing Samuel, I'll take care of this in future